# MYSQL Node Issue

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, web

Running the below code throws a MYSQL err, I've checked the syntax and it seems correct but not sure why the error is being thrown.

```
app.post('/:roomname/create',function(request, response){
let roomID =  ""+request.params.roomname+"";
console.log(roomID);
let insertRoom = "INSERT INTO chatrooms (roomname) VALUES (?)";


conn.query(insertRoom,[roomID], function(error, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
console.log("1 record inserted");
});
```

Error:

```
node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
    throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
    ^
```

ReferenceError: err is not defined

Comment: Could you post the actual JavaScript used?

Comment: `"INSERT INTO room (roomname) VALUES ('"+roomID+"')";`. put single quote arround the variable

Comment: New code posted @MattPengelly

Answer (score 1):

Your handling error name and callback error name  is not same!
you must define same error name in both callback and handling block.
Please check use this snipet. After use this snipet if any error happening, please let me know in comment.

```
app.post('/:roomname/create',function(request, response){
let roomID =  ""+request.params.roomname+"";
console.log(roomID);
let insertRoom = "INSERT INTO chatrooms (roomname) VALUES (?)";


conn.query(insertRoom,[roomID], function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
console.log("1 record inserted");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
conn.query(insertRoom,[roomID], function(error, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
```

In the callback function you are writing "error" but in the if you are checking "err". In the callback change it to

```
conn.query(insertRoom,[roomID], function(err, result) {
```